# Convert a Numpy 2 dimensional array to a mapped list of dictionaries

Tags: python, numpy

I have a Numpy 2D array, and a list of headers. Each row of the Numpy array is a record to be mapped to the header list. In the end, I want to convert each record to a dictionary (and so have a list of dictionaries). For example:

```
A = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
headers = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Output:

```
[{'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3}, {'a' : 4, 'b' : 5, 'c' : 6}]
```

What is the fastest way to achieve this in Python? I have in the order of 10^4 rows and 10 headers, and running it is taking me roughly 0.3 seconds.

At this moment, I have the following code:

```
current_samples = A # The samples described above as input, a Numpy array
locations = []
for i, sample in enumerate(current_samples):
    current_location = dict()
    for index, dimension in enumerate(headers):
        current_location[dimension] = sample[index]
    locations.append(current_location)
```

Comment: Out of interest, what is your use case that 300 ms seems slow? Are you evaluating likelihoods, or is it a web service..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) + [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
result = [dict(zip(headers, l)) for l in A]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}]
```

With `zip` you create pair of items from the list and pass it to the dictionary constructor.

Comment: Thanks. I tested it and it reduces the time from 0.3 seconds to 0.07 seconds. Thats roughly 4.5 times improvement.

Answer (score 0):

You could (somewhat over-killed) use `pandas` for this purpose:

```
result = pd.DataFrame(A, columns=headers).to_dict('row')
```

Output:

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}]
```